# How can I browse local project documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rdoc, ri

Is there any Rails way to browse the documentation generated in local `doc/` folder with the command `rake doc:app`?

I know I could configure Apache to serve the files in the doc folder but I would be surprised if Rails didn't provide a way to do that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason Rails doesn't provide a way to serve it is because it's just static HTML - you can open it in your browser directly (eg. `firefox doc/app/index.html`), without the need for a server.

If you wanted, you could add your own Rake task for this in `lib/tasks/browserdoc.rake`:

```
namespace :doc do
    desc "Browse application documentation"
    task :open do
        `firefox doc/app/index.html`
    end
end
```

Some systems have browser-agnostic shortcuts you could use instead of hard-coding the browser name; `open` on Mac OSX will open an HTML file in your current browser, as will `sensible-browser` on most modern Linux systems.

Comment: Fair enough. For the record, I symlinked the `doc` folder into `/var/www/` so that Apache knew it had to serve the pages: `sudo ln -s ~/www/yourownpoet/doc /var/www/yopdoc`